# C# - Closest number to 0

Tags: c#, numbers, closest

I apologize if it sounds dumb, I am a beginner in programming. 
Can somebody explain how can I get the closest number to 0 if for example:

A = -13

B = 5

How can I do this so it can display that in this example B is closest to 0?

I tried some thing with "if" but can't seem to get it work.

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Using `if` sounds like you are on the right track. Think about what closest to zero means as a mathematical/logical statement. Also, post your code here.

Comment: `Math.Abs` and the `<` operator should do the trick.

Comment: `Math.Min(Math.Abs(a), Math.Abs(b))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel taking a risk to answer that but if you try to say theirs [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) with term *closest*, you can use [`Math.Abs` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and compare them like;

```
if(Math.Abs(A) > Math.Abs(B))
{
   // B is closer than A
}
else if(Math.Abs(B) > Math.Abs(A))
{
   // A is closer than B
}
else
{
   // They are equal close to zero.
}
```

It is not clear what are `A` and `B` types but this method accepts `short`, `int`, `long`, `decimal`, `double`, `float` etc..